# SQL Distinct Syntax

Tags: mysql

Starting to learn SQL, right now I'm using mysql to start off. Currently stuck on one problem on my SQL homework in which I have to:

Show all genres in which there is at least one title.  List each genre only once.

Tried using command line:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Genre, Title, FROM Titles;
```

Does not give me my desired result.

[image]

Can anyone please show me, what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the schema of the tables you're using.

Comment: distinct is same for mysql and oracle: Read this http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php

Answer (score 2):

your task is to show genres, why do you need title in query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Genre FROM Titles;
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi yes, if this genre in titles table - it has at least one title already

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Genre, Title FROM Titles WHERE Title <> '' GROUP BY Genre;
```

See example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a8453/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Titles where Titles is not null
group by Genre
```

Answer (score 0):

you use comma after Tilte that is wrong syntax.

This wright way is

```
SELECT Genre, Title FROM Titles WHERE Title IS NOT NULL GROPU BY Genre;
```